# Try to make TabLayout in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs, android-viewpager

I followed some tutorial to make a `Tablayout` in android,
but I have a problem.

FirstActivity.java :

```
package info.mandai.animegallery;

import com.example.animegallery.R;
import info.mandai.animegallery.adapter.TabsPagerAdapter;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class FirstActivity extends FragmentActivity implements -----> Error Here
    ActionBar.TabListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;

private String[] tabs = { "Registrasi", "Login", "A" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }
}
}
```

On the word "FirstActivity" I have this error:
they said **"The type FirstActivity must implement the inherited abstract method ActionBar.TabListener.onTabSelected(ActionBar$Tab, FragmentTransaction)**

What do I do to fix it?

Comment: Do you have the correct imports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add following code to your class

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

   // do something
}
```